Can a polymorphed Will-O-Wisp use Natural Invisibility?

Sneaking or scouting:

Will-O’-Wisp: 9 HD, Small, Fly 50 (perfect), Str 1, Dex 29, Con 10

Normally, you do not gain Special Abilities of a creature, however, you do gain abilities that are "natural abilities"
Natural Invisibility (Ex): A startled or frightened will-o’-wisp can extinguish its glow, effectively becoming invisible as the spell (questionable)

I saw this in a polymorph handbook for DND 3R. Is there a rule to support this, like an official definition of "natural ability"?

Natural abilities are defined on p. 180 of the Player's Handbook as:

Natural Abilities:  This category includes abilities a creature has because of its physical nature, such as a bird's ability to fly.  Natural abilities are those not otherwise designated as extraordinary, supernatural, or spell-like.

The will-o'-wisp's natural invisibility special quality says:

Natural Invisibility (Ex)
A startled or frightened will-o’-wisp can extinguish its glow, effectively becoming invisible as the spell.

So no, Natural Invisibility cannot be a natural ability, because it is designated as extraordinary.
Polymorph's description specifically calls out that the caster:

...does not gain the extraordinary special qualities possessed by the new form

...which unambiguously covers a will-o'-wisp's invisibility, so the spell will not make you invisible if you transform into a will-o'-wisp.
